# Why RESTful servics should be stateless? What's the benefit?

Tags: web-services, rest

I have heard enough about `RESTful service should be stateless. All state info should be stored in client. And each request should contain all the necessary state info`.

But why? What's the benefit of doing that? `Only when I know its benefit/motivation can I use it properly.`

What if my client have a huge amount of state? Suppose there's an online document editing application. Does client have to send the full text he/she is editing when calling server's RESTful API? Or is this scenario simply not suitable for RESTful approach?

Comment: "*Suppose there's an online document editing application. Does client have to send the full text he/she is editing when calling server's RESTful API?*" Then how would the document be made available to other clients? Statelessness refers to *client* state, not world state accessible to multiple clients. And, in any event, a document ID would serve to identify the document.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well, I admit that's not a good example. But I think there can be some scenario where the state info is big.

Comment: Like most complex design trade-offs, the right answer depends on the details of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When talking about REST (or well RESTful since not many people adhere 100% to the paper I will quote here) services I always think it's best to start with the source, meaning [Fielding dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf) which mentions in `5.1.3 Stateless`:

> This constraint induces the properties of visibility, reliability, and scalability. Visibility
>   is improved because a monitoring system does not have to look beyond a single request
>   datum in order to determine the full nature of the request. Reliability is improved because
>   it eases the task of recovering from partial failures [133]. Scalability is improved because
>   not having to store state between requests allows the server component to quickly free
>   resources, and further simplifies implementation because the server doesn’t have to
>   manage resource usage across requests.

It goes even further talking about its trade-offs:

> Like most architectural choices, the stateless constraint reflects a design trade-off. The
>   disadvantage is that it may decrease network performance by increasing the repetitive data
>   (per-interaction overhead) sent in a series of requests, since that data cannot be left on the
>   server in a shared context. In addition, placing the application state on the client-side
>   reduces the server’s control over consistent application behavior, since the application
>   becomes dependent on the correct implementation of semantics across multiple client
>   versions.

But Fielding doesn't stop even there, he talks about caching to overcome some of the problems.

I highly recommend you go through that PDF, since (from what I remember) that was the original paper that introduced REST.

The use case you provided is a tough one and as many said it depends on your exact scenario. `RESTful` services are called `restFUL` and not `REST` because people found the original paper too limiting and decided to loosen up a bit the rules (for instance the original paper doesn't say anything about batch operations).

Answer (score 2):

The primary benefit is scalability -- by not needing to fetch additional context for each request, you minimize the amount of work done by the server, which may need to service many requests at the same time.

Additionally, it helps provide greater clarity to consumers of your API. By having the user send everything related to the operation being done, they can more clearly see *what* is actually being done, and the error messages they get can often be more direct as a result; an error can say what value is wrong and why, rather than trying to communicate that something the consumer can't see went wrong on the server.

Answer (score 1):

From the same chapter of Fielding's dissertation:

> Like most architectural choices, the stateless constraint reflects a
>   design trade-off. **The disadvantage is that it may decrease network
>   performance by increasing the repetitive data** (per-interaction
>   overhead) sent in a series of requests, since that data cannot be left
>   on the server in a shared context.

Advantages are explained as follows:

> This constraint induces the properties of visibility, reliability, and
>   scalability.
>
> **Visibility** is improved because a monitoring system does
>   not have to look beyond a single request datum in order to determine
>   the full nature of the request.
>
> **Reliability** is improved because it
>   eases the task of recovering from partial failures [133].
>
> **Scalability** is improved because not having to store state between requests allows
>   the server component to quickly free resources, and further simplifies
>   implementation because the server doesn't have to manage resource
>   usage across requests.

---

Regarding your specific case, yes and no. This is how the Web works. When we edit something online, we send entire request to the server. Though it is a design choice how we implement partial updates.

Software can be designed to accomplish this goal by sending PUT/POST requests to sub-resources. For example:

```
PUT /book/chapter1 HTTP/1.1

PUT /book/chapter2 HTTP/1.1

PUT /book/chapter3 HTTP/1.1
```

instead of updating whole resource:

```
PUT /book HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xyz
Content-Length: ...
```

Comment: This is a good point. REST should be viewed as a set of (not even very strict) rules to ease the process of developing for the web. How far do you want to go in respecting those rules is up to you.